# Dependencies are not deploying into tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat, myeclipse

Recently I just switched from Myeclipse 2014 (spring version) to Eclipse Java EE. having add tomcat 6 and afterwards deploying my web project(war packaging) into that, seeing that none of it's dependencies added into folder WEB-INF/classes and I get ClassNotFoundException all the time. deploying this project into Myeclipse tomcat works out fine. why is that happening?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the project facet for web project and add dependencies to deployment assembly.

1. Right click on the project and select properties.
2. In the search box on the window(left upper corner), type project facet.
3. Make sure that "Dynamic Web Module" is checked along with other necessary facets(like Java, Java Script...)
4. Again in the search box, type deployment assembly.
5. Click the add button on the right hand side and add the dependencies you wanted to add to the deployment assembly for your project.
6. Now clean and build your project in eclipse and deploy it on server.
7. It should have all the dependent libraries in the classpath(WEB-INF/lib) now. So it should work ok.

Comment: The dependencies are the open projects in eclipse. Anyways, I did all the things you mentioned, not working though.

Comment: How do you add the dependent libraries into the deployment assembly? 
If you add them properly, they should be shown up in the deployment directory, when you clean and build the project.

Comment: I add them according to your structure, still not working. the problem is that, the projects as dependencies, become as jar files and deploy in lib folder, otherwise, they should be compiled and get place in classes folder.